# Flink keyed TestHarness not using keyed Streams

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, flink-streaming

im struggling writing unit tests with the test harness.

Within my test class I am initialising a `KeyedTwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness` to test a `KeyedCoProcessFunction`

But when I setup and open the test harness it throws:

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: Keyed state can only be used on a 'keyed stream', i.e., after a 'keyBy()' operation.
```

I don't know what's wrong here?
One guess is a dependency problem, because I couldn't find the Harnesses within `flink-streaming-java:1.16.1` i have additionally `flink-streaming-java_2.11:1.14.1` package here. Could this be the problem?
If yes, what is the correct package for flink 1.16.1 Test Harnesses?

Testclass:

```java
public class BuildAssetNodeContextTest extends TestBase {
 
    private KeyedTwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness testHarness;
    private BuildAssetNodeContext buildAssetNodeContext; // <-- function to test 

    @BeforeEach
    public void setupTestHarness() throws Exception {
        buildAssetNodeContext = new BuildAssetNodeContext<>();

        testHarness = new KeyedTwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<>(
            new KeyedCoProcessOperator<>(buildAssetNodeContext),
            new OperationalDataAssetNodeIdKeySelector<>(),
            new AssetNodeParameterIdKeySelector(),
            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO
        );

        testHarness.setup();
        testHarness.open();
    }
}
```

Function to Test:

```java
public class BuildAssetNodeContext<ANDPayloadType extends OperationalDataPayload> extends KeyedCoProcessFunction<String, ANDBusinessObject<ANDPayloadType>, ParaBusinessObject<AssetNodeParameterPayload>, AssetNodeContext> {

    private ValueState<AssetNodeContext> currentAssetNodeContext;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        currentAssetNodeContext = getRuntimeContext().getState(
            new ValueStateDescriptor<>("currentAssetNodeContext", AssetNodeContext.class)
        ); // <-- `NullPointerException` throws here 
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement1(ANDBusinessObject<ANDPayloadType> operationalData, KeyedCoProcessFunction<String, ANDBusinessObject<ANDPayloadType>, ParaBusinessObject<AssetNodeParameterPayload>, AssetNodeContext>.Context ctx, Collector<AssetNodeContext> out) throws Exception {
        log.info(String.format("received operational data event: %s", operationalData));

    }

    @Override
    public void processElement2(ParaBusinessObject<AssetNodeParameterPayload> assetNodeParameter, KeyedCoProcessFunction<String, ANDBusinessObject<ANDPayloadType>, ParaBusinessObject<AssetNodeParameterPayload>, AssetNodeContext>.Context ctx, Collector<AssetNodeContext> out) throws Exception {
        log.info(String.format("received asset node parameter event: %s", assetNodeParameter));
    }
}
```

Project POM:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Flink -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.smallrye.config</groupId>
            <artifactId>smallrye-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- necessary for smallrye config to work properly, without you will get an -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Code generation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- (De-)Serialisation -->

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TESTING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
            <!--
            TODO: Challenge version
                Where are the Stream Operators (like 'KeyedTwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness') for 1.16 located
            -->
            <version>1.14.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!--
            Build a fat jar to include all necessary dependencies in the jar-file
            See: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/configuration/maven/#template-for-creating-an-uberfat-jar-with-dependencies
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <!-- Replace this with the main class of your job -->
                                    <mainClass>...</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
I couldn't found the `KeyedTwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness` because `flink-streaming-java` needs to be added again but with  `<classifier>tests</classifier>`.

After adding this to my `pom.xml` it works fine:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
```